# I can't run the script output by gradle build: "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a `build.gradle` file like:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    ...
}

compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-Aproject=${project.group}/${project.name}"]
}

application {
    mainClass = 'com.anentropic.myproj.MyProj'
    applicationName = "myproj"  // shell script wrapper name
}

jar {
    archiveBaseName = "myproj"  // jar name
}
```

It compiles fine when I run `gradle build`.

There is an artefact output at `app/build/scripts/myproj` which is a shell script that wraps the invocation of `java` with my jar file

When I run it I get:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.anentropic.myproj.MyProj
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.anentropic.myproj.MyProj
```

So that's not very useful. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it won't work from `build/scripts` folder ; the proper way is to unzip the distribution (.zip or .tar) from 'build/distributions/' into a new folder (creates a bin and lib folders) and then run the script from 'bin'

reason - the script (default) is expects the `bin and lib` structure for resolving paths.

Comment: So the script is a useless artefact?

Comment: its not built for way you are trying to use. distribution convention (at least the default gradle template) sets it to use it else where (any where with bin and lib). you are free to write your own script.

Comment: Thanks, I unzipped the package that was under build/distributions and it extracted bin and lib folders, there was `bin/myproj` in there which I can run fine. Not sure the purpose of the non-working `build/scripts/myproj` script, maybe `gradle run` uses that? ‍♂️